# cURL HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2) in php

Tags: php, curl

Trying to curl url

https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-03-14/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC

and get error 92 * HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Have enabled verbose logging to try to troubleshoot:

- Host api.beta.tab.com.au:443 was resolved.
- IPv6: (none)
- IPv4: 23.206.199.8, 23.206.199.16, 23.206.199.9, 23.206.199.33, 23.206.199.26, 23.206.199.11, 23.206.199.25, 23.206.199.10, 23.206.199.18
- Trying 23.206.199.8:443...
- Connected to api.beta.tab.com.au (23.206.199.8) port 443
- ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
- CAfile: C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
- CApath: none
- SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / X25519 / id-ecPublicKey
- ALPN: server accepted h2
- Server certificate:
- subject: C=AU; ST=Victoria; L=Docklands; O=TABCORP ASSETS PTY LTD; CN=*.beta.tab.com.au
- start date: Feb 10 00:00:00 2024 GMT
- expire date: Feb 12 23:59:59 2025 GMT
- subjectAltName: host "api.beta.tab.com.au" matched cert's "*.beta.tab.com.au"
- issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
- SSL certificate verify ok.
- Certificate level 0: Public key type EC/prime256v1 (256/128 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
- Certificate level 1: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
- Certificate level 2: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha1WithRSAEncryption
- old SSL session ID is stale, removing
- using HTTP/2
- [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-03-13/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC
- [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
- [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
- [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: api.beta.tab.com.au]
- [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-03-13/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC]
- [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]

> GET /v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-03-13/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC HTTP/2
> Host: api.beta.tab.com.au
> Accept: */*

- HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

This is the function that I'm using:

function fetchDataFromUrl($url) {

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
  
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
$curl_error_number = curl_errno($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    echo "cURL error: $error_message | cURL error number: $curl_error_number | http code: $http_code\n\n";
    curl_close($ch);
    return $error_message;
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "cURL success\n\n";
    return $data;
}
```

}

And just a simple call:

$url = "https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-03-13/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC";
$response = fetchDataFromUrl($url);

Have tested curl with other HTTPS sites and working fine, so seems particular to the url in question.

If I try to force HTTP to version 1 or 1.1, the script just hangs with no response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The response should be a json array.

Comment: And I can access the url without issue from a browser on the same PC